Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 5.15
I want to install Ubuntu 22.04 but with kernel 5.15
I downloaded ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso and installed it but it is shipped with kernel 6.8. Also tried 22.04, 22.04.4 and 22.04.5
uname -r gives 6.8* . Updates while download was also disabled.
Any idea where I can get a Ubuntu 22.04 iso image with kernel 5.15

This question is similar to: How to select GA (non-HWE) kernel during Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS installation?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This may be a XY Problem. Why do you want to use that kernel?

my tool only works with that kernel

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Desktop includes the 5.15 kernel on it, which is what is used with the live session, and installed too.
That ISO can be found at

https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/22.04.1/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso

with the manifest or contents found at

https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/22.04.1/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.manifest

If you examine the manifest you'll see it contains
linux-generic-hwe-22.04         5.15.0.43.44
linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic   5.15.0-43.46

which is what you're asking for, HOWEVER as its the HWE or Hardware Enablement kernel that is installed by default for Ubuntu Desktop, thus it'll upgrade to 6.8 which is the current HWE kernel (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)
Media that uses/installs the GA kernel stack will remain 5.15 after upgrade, but Ubuntu Desktop ISOs since 20.04 have come with the HWE kernel stack.
The GA kernel (package I also listed) is also found on the installation media as an OEM option, but it is not installed during a normal install UNLESS it's detected as a better option as part of OEM kernel processing
Ubuntu Server ISOs install with the GA kernel stack, as do older flavor media at 22.04 & 22.04.1 (later or .2 & higher flavor media uses HWE same as Ubuntu Desktop)

so there is no way i get an Ubuntu 22.04 desktop iso that installs kernel 5 ?

Download and install the Ubuntu 22.04 or 22.04.1 Desktop ISO, and install it offline (so the kernel can NOT upgrade).  Then reboot & perform the package changes as per the link I provided (before updating) to switch the system to GA kernel stack (search 'downgrade' which is the term used in that doc), and your system will remain on the GA or 5.15 kernel for the life of the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop. The early flavor ISOs (ie. 22.04 & 22.04.1) installed the 5.15 GA kernel stack thus those installs will still be using it; flavor ISOs didn't switch to HWE until 22.04.2 & later
